# Merge multiple dataframes on date with not same values

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4 dataframes: `jpn`, `swe`, `svk`, `aut`, where every dataframe has two columns `year` and `~_co2` and some index, which I dont care about.

```py
>>>swe
        year    swe_co2
20105   1834    0.033
20106   1839    0.044

>>>svk
        year    svk_co2
15247   1840    0.013
15248   1841    0.023
```

Every dataframe has structure like this, but the `year` columns doesn't start in the same year for every value.

I would like to join this dataframes to create a new dataframe like this

```py
>>>merger

        year    swe_co2    svk_co2
1       1834    0.033      None
2       1839    0.044      None
3       1840    0.047      0.013
4       1841    None       0.023
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([swe, svk], ignore_index=True)

    year    swe_co2 svk_co2
0   1834    0.033   NaN
1   1839    0.044   NaN
2   1840    NaN     0.013
3   1841    NaN     0.023
```

If you have more than two dataframes, just append them in that list `[swe, svk, df3, df4, ...]`

Comment: also I would like to ask: this method created duplicates in `year` column, like 4 times `2019` for every `df`, is there a way to merge it to one?

Comment: Can you give an example of inputs and desired output? How would you like those duplicates get merged?

Comment: it looks like 4 lines of 2019 where every of four new columns has a one value in one of the 2019 and others are NaN, I would like to merger this 4x `2019` inside one, without the NaN values

Answer (score 1):

```
df_list=[jpn,svk,aut]
```

via `concat()` and `merge()`:

```
merger=pd.concat((swe.merge(x,on='year',how='outer') for x in df_list))
```

**Note:** I think `concat()` alone will give you desired output but if you didn't get then try with `concat()` and `merge()`